# How can I evaluate the performance of a object detector at a fixed confidence threshold?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, metrics

I have an object detector and now I have to decide which confidence threshold to use for each class. How can I determine what is the best confidence threshold for each class?
Once decided, how can I evaluate this model at the given confidence threshold?

Everybody seems to just be using variations of AP, which though evaluates the model at different confidence thresholds.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose by confidence threshold you mean the the minimum value of IoU (intersection-over-union) to accept a detection.

If so use a *validation-set* to determine the best confidence threshold by means of a **precision-recall curve**:

1. Apply the object detector on the validation data.
2. Sort predictions by score (or confidence).
3. Compute a precision/recall point for each subset of top detections.

All the points make a PR curve, and each point provides you the value of precision and recall (see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html) for more details) for a given confidence.

To determine which confidence threshold is the best for your application you have to pick the value in correspondence of a point on the curve that has the desired precision (or recall) or trade-off (e.g. true positive vs false positive) between the two.

Note: the area under the PR curve is your *average precision* (AP).

---

**Edit:** Find a suitable classification threshold `t` (rather than 0.5) on validation data.

**Approach 1:** suppose you build a PR (or ROC) curve from predictions `p` and labels `y`, e.g. `precision, recall, thresholds = pr_curve(p, y)`. You have to determine which quantity (precision vs recall) is best for your application (*note: this is application specific*). Say you want your model to achieve `precision = 0.9`, so pick `t` such that:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve

precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(p, y)

# find the threshold that achieves 90% precision
index = (np.abs(np.array(precision) - 0.9)).argmin()
t = thresholds[index]
```

Intuitively it's like finding the point on the curve that best fits your application.

**Approach 2:** determine `t` by maximizing a given metric. I'm not aware of general metrics, but in particle physics a common formula is the *significance*: `s / sqrt(s + b)` where `s` is your positive class (the signal), and `b` the negative class (the background, in jargon.) This looks like:

```py
import numpy as np

def significance(p: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, t: float) -> float:
    pred_y = (p > t).astype(y.dtype)

    s = pred_y[y == 1].sum()
    b = pred_y[y == 0].sum()

    return s / np.sqrt(s + b)

# classification thresholds (adjust `num` as desired)
thresholds = np.linspace(0, 1, endpoint=False, num=100)

# compute significance metric for each t
scores = np.array([significance(p, y, t) for t in thresholds])
scores[np.isnan(scores) | np.isinf(scores)] = 0  # avoid NaNs

# threshold that maximizes the formula:
thresholds[scores.argmax()]
```

**Approach 3:** I found in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1812.04606) paper a metric called `FPRN` that evaluates the *false positive rate* at a given percentage (N%) of the *true positive rate* - this is used for out-of-distribution detection but it works also in classification. As the authors say, the metric represents the performance at *one strict threshold*. In the same spirit of approach 2, you can compute the FPRN metric either at given values of `N` in [0, 1] or along the full range with `np.linspace`. In this way you can pick the threshold `t` that minimizes `FPNR` (since for this metric lower is better) or correspondent to the `N` that best suits your problem.

Comment: No I mean the threshold that you use to decide whether the model predicts a class or not.

Comment: Given a certain IoU threshold it is very clear how to compute the mAP. However, in no papers I found a single metric that evaluates the model at a certain confidence threshold. 

By confidence threshold I mean the following. Suppose your model returns a prediction p for class c, then you consider the class predicted if p >= t, t being the confidence threshold.

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check that